# Are there some criteria that I should consider with text inputs?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i am near to publish an app developed by flutter .

in my app there many of text inputs that user handle with. like filling a text then save it to the server . here i am using `Firestore` as a backend to `my app`

for my side there nothing special to filter the text before save it to `Firestore`

my question is : Are there a common special criteria of inputs that i should use filter for ? Such as letters, symbols, or any other entry that may bring errors or harm operations flow either my application or my storage in `Firestore` ?

Note : Most of the operations in my app are to fill in a `text field` then save it to `Firestore` then finally display it using Text `Widget`

any advises ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to (client side checks are still good to have though). If some weird ASCII art is not supported by Firestore as document IDs or field names, it'll just reject the operation. For the field value it's just plaintext and should not harm.

However, if you application's data can be accessed by multiple users e.g. a blog/articles app, you might want to use [Firestore triggers for Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions) to filter any spam text or malicious scripts (especially if you plan to run a web app with the same).